# How to solve network response error 417 in Volley?

Tags: android

I passed both header and params even-though it shows exception failed error 417.
I checked every line.
It works for an API, but it does not work for a particular API?

Please, help me

Comment: did you provide all mandatory parameters to API call

Comment: call your API using postman and check its working or not?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be more detailed? Where is your code? and your full logcat? Which are the APIs you're talking about?

Comment: it was works in posman ? not in code..

Answer (score 0):

**Error 417 :**
The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) contains a 'Expect' request which can not be satisfied. The Expect request is fairly generic i.e. loosely defined in the HTTP protocol. It can specify more than one expectation, each of which may be interpreted differently by different Web servers.

**Fixing 417 errors - general**
This error seldom occurs in most Web traffic, particularly when the client system is a Web browser. This type of Web traffic seldom uses an 'Expect' request.

If your client system is not a Web browser, the problem can only be resolved by examining what the client is trying to do then discussing with your ISP why the Web server fails the 'Expect' request sent by the client system.

Comment: if you find answer helpful please mark it as accepted